# Why does `at` remove my scheduled events?

Tags: command-line, cron, schedule

I set an `at` scheduler command like

```
at -f **its_time** 23:57
```

when in the **its_time** file I put

```
libreoffice /home/user/ist_time.odt
```

I scheduled but the "system" or whatever is removing yourself my `at` commands.
I check `atq` and they are there.
But when the time’s up, the `at` command doesn't execute.

What’s going on?

Answer (score -1):

Read `man at`. Your `at` job doesn't have access to your `DISPLAY`, and `libreoffice` wants access. If you want to access your display, read `man xhost`, and add `export DISPLAY=:0` to your `at` job.

Beware: The `at` environment differs from your interactive environment. I often run `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)` in various environments to keep track. I've used this in  `at`, `batch`, `cron`, `interactive`, `interactive ssh`, `non-gui`, `ssh` and `term` environments.

Comment: Thanks man. I need to study more. This is another level that i am not still in. Thanks